# DownloadManager behaviour on directory creation

Tags: android, android-download-manager

There are some similar questions have been asked, but mine is a bit different, i have the following code to do a download on my application:

```
 DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
                        .setTitle(fileInfo.getFileName())
                        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                                getString(R.string.app_name) + File.separator + fileInfo.getFileName());

                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    }
 manager.enqueue(request);
```

This works fine without complaining on at least Samsung S4, Nexus 4, Nexus 7, however i recently found out that on some devices it fails to create the directory with the error:

so now i am checking for the directory and creating if it doesn't exist with

```
File downloadDir = new File (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                            + File.separator + getString(R.string.app_name));

                    if (!downloadDir.exists()){
                        boolean mkdir = downloadDir.mkdir();
                    }
```

My question is why DownloadManager behaves different is this an Android version or vendor issue and what is the expected behaviour, since the documentation for `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` states that it might throw an `IllegalStateException: IllegalStateException If the external storage directory cannot be found or created.`

I assumed it should try to create the directory in that case there should be no reason or need for me to use the `mkdir` function but it isn't so

Comment: can you paste the logs

Comment: @RahulPatil i can but this is more an expected behaviour question, the error irs `Failed to create target file /storage/emulated/0/Download/µECS/AU3110005_AU3110006_Celulas não linfoides.pdf
            at com.android.providers.downloads.Helpers.getFullPath(Helpers.java:204)`     its fixed if i create the µECS directory myself like i said on question i just want to know if im supposed to or not by the doc i can't understand

Answer (score 3):

I had the same behavior on LG G3 without subdirectory creation:

```
W/DownloadManager: Aborting request for download 544: Failed to create target file /storage/emulated/0/Download/Sub Directory/IMG_20150422_160932.jpg
               com.android.providers.downloads.StopRequestException: Failed to create target file /storage/emulated/0/Download/Sub Directory/IMG_20150422_160932.jpg
                   at com.android.providers.downloads.Helpers.getFullPath(Helpers.java:213)
                   at com.android.providers.downloads.Helpers.generateSaveFile(Helpers.java:166)
                   at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadThread.processResponseHeaders(DownloadThread.java:2054)
                   at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadThread.access$500(DownloadThread.java:130)
                   at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadThread$ContentAnalyzer.init(DownloadThread.java:274)
                   at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadThread.executeDownload(DownloadThread.java:922)
                   at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadThread.runInternal(DownloadThread.java:784)
```

calling this method before helps:

```
        private void createDirectoryIfNecessary() {
            File downloadDir = new File (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                    + File.separator + subdirectory);
            if (!downloadDir.exists()){
                downloadDir.mkdirs();
            }
        }
```